# jQuery slider is not draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-slider

I am using jQuery slider in my ruby on rails app. The problem is I am unable to drag slider button, but it moves successfully if I click at any place inside slider.

[image]

view file

```
<div id="slider"></div>
<%= text_field_tag :search_radius, params[:search_radius], placeholder: "2 miles", class: "search_radius" %>
```

js file

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#slider").slider({
    step:1,
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    value: $('input.search_radius').val(), // needed to persist value after page reload
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".search_radius").val(ui.value);
    },
  change: function() {
   $('input.search_radius').val( $( "#slider" ).slider( "value"));
    },
        create: function() {
    $('input.search_radius').val( $( "#slider" ).slider( ""));
  }
  });
$(".search_radius").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
```

css file

```
#slider {
 width:100px ;
 height:11px;
 background:url(slider/slider-bg.png);
 margin-left: 10px;
 position:relative;
 padding:0 10px;
}

/*Style for the slider button*/
.ui-slider-handle {
 width:24px !important;
 height:24px !important;
 position:absolute !important;
 top:-7px !important;
 margin-left:-12px !important;
 z-index:200 !important;
 background:url("slider/slider-button.png") !important;
 border: none !important;
 display: block !important;
}

/*Result div where the slider value is displayed*/
#search_radius {
 font-size:20px;
 height:$searchInputsHeight;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:green;
 width:80px;
 text-align:center;
 text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
 font-weight:700;
 display:inline;
}
```

application.css

```
 *= require jquery.ui.slider
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ui
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.slider
```

Comment: What do you get if you print $('input.search_radius').val() in the console?

Comment: Console gives "2", I found out my problem persist only  in Safari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the console in firebug to see if the javascript is working fine?

It does sound like a z-index problem but it looks like you have tried to address that already.
Maybe also try using the firebug 'inspect element' tool to make sure nothing is at a z-index above the slider.

If possible send a link to an example and I will have a look

Comment: Thank you, unegma. I've created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icherevkov/7exDA/) and it seems that you are right about z-index, I will check it

Comment: I tested it on the mobile preview and it is not dragging.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, at first look it all looks good. Could you please try by removing  - change and create like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#slider").slider({
    step:1,
    range: "max",
    min: 1,
    max: 10,
    value: $('input.search_radius').val(), // needed to persist value after page reload
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $(".search_radius").val(ui.value);
    }
  });
$(".search_radius").val($("#slider").slider("value"));
```

Comment: Hello, Aleks! Unfortunately, it doesn't make any changes

Comment: could you please create an example on http://jsfiddle.net/ so I could take a look it faster. If you have tried to use it.

Comment: Thank you, Aleks. I've created [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/icherevkov/7exDA/) and everything works correctly. So it seems that the problem is in z-index as unegma guessed

Comment: According to the example it seems now that is fixed :) Thanks for giving me +1 for simple proposal to create an example :)